# Как сделать ссылку активной у статической страницы?

Tags: php, html, css, yii2

Всем привет.

Как сделать ссылку активной у статической страницы?

Например у не статической страницы можно было бы проверить ссылку так.

```
    <li class="<?= $this->context->action->id == 'help' ? 'active' : '' ?>"></li>
```

Как схожее реализовать со статической страницей?

Вот так в контроллере создается статическая страница

```
public function actions(){
    return [
        'help' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            'viewPrefix' => 'pages',
        ],
    ];
```

Вывод на вьюшке

```
     $str = '';
        $str .= Html::tag(
            'li',
            Html::a('помощь',
                Url::to([
                    '/help',
                    ])
            ),
            [
                'class' => 'active', // как здесь проверить?
            ]
        );

    echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Офф документация
[Class yii\web\ViewAction](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-viewaction#$viewParam-detail)

```
    <li class="<?= Yii::$app->request->get('view') == 'help' ? 'active' : '' ?>"></li>
```